# Chemistry of Benedict's Reagent

Tags: biochemistry

I want to understand what is the exact mechanism by which "**enediols**"  reduce cupric to cuprous of  Benedict's reagent.

> The principle of Benedict's test is that when reducing sugars are heated in the presence of an alkali they are converted to powerful reducing species known as enediols. Enediols reduce the cupric compounds (Cu2+) present in the Benedict's reagent to cuprous compounds (Cu+) which are precipitated as insoluble red copper(I) oxide(Cu2O).
>   [[source]](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benedict%27s_reagent)

Any reference would be helpful too.

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/46577/why-is-vitamin-c-called-an-antioxidant answers it